# Throw java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on http:/ when i try to download txt file from server

Tags: android, spring, retrofit, retrofit2, rx-android

i get fail (java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on http:)when i try to download file(.txt) from server. I cant understand where problem(on server or on client). I download this file from broswer and postman and haven't problems. I think problem in client but cant understand where.

```
@RestController
public class DownloadDbController {
   @RequestMapping(path = "/download", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ResponseEntity<Resource> download(String param) throws IOException {
       File file = new File("src/main/res/123.txt");

       HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
       header.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=123.txt");


       Path path = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath());
       ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(Files.readAllBytes(path));

       return ResponseEntity.ok()
               .headers(header)
               .contentLength(file.length())
               .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
               .body(resource);

   }
}
```

Api:

```
public interface GetDb {
@Streaming
@GET("{url}")
Observable<ResponseBody> downloadDB(@Path("url") String url);
}
```

retrofit class:

```
public class RetrofitService {
private static RetrofitService mInstance;
private static final String BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/";
private Retrofit mRetrofit;


private RetrofitService() {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
            .addInterceptor(interceptor);

    mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .client(client.build())
            .build();
}

public static RetrofitService getInstance() {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new RetrofitService();
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public GetDb getJSONApi() {
    return mRetrofit.create(GetDb.class);
  }
}
```

And class where i trying to download and write to new file

```
public class SyncDb {
Context mContext;

public SyncDb(Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

public void downloadDB(String path) {
    RetrofitService.getInstance()
            .getJSONApi()
            .downloadDB("download")
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Observer<ResponseBody>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(ResponseBody responseBody) {

                        saveFile(responseBody);
                    Log.d("abc","onNext");


                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.d("abc","error");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    Log.d("abc","Completed");
                }
            });

   public void saveFile( ResponseBody responseBody ) {
    File folder =new File(mContext.getFilesDir().toString(), "123.txt");
    folder.mkdirs();

    File unzipMe = new File(folder, "123.txt");
    if (!unzipMe.exists()){
        try {
            unzipMe.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
    try {
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(unzipMe));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        bos.write(responseBody.bytes());
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add protocols(listOf(Protocol.HTTP_1_1)) line to your OkHttpClient.

Example;

```
val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .protocols(listOf(Protocol.HTTP_1_1))
                    .readTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .connectTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
                    .addInterceptor(authInterceptor)
                    .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
                    .build()
```